# Recursive function not working as planned

Tags: scheme, lisp, sisc

I am writing a function in Scheme that is supposed to take two integers, X and Y, and then recursively add `X/Y + (X-1)/(Y-1) + ...`until one of the numbers reaches 0.

*For example, take 4 and 3:*

`4/3 + 3/2 + 2/1 = 29/6`

Here is my function which is not working correctly:

```
(define changingFractions (lambda (X Y)
    (cond 
        ( ((> X 0) and (> Y 0)) (+ (/ X Y) (changingFunctions((- X 1) (- Y 1)))))
        ( ((= X 0) or (= Y 0)) 0)
    )
))
```

**EDIT:** I have altered my code to fix the problem listed in the comments, as well as changing the location of `or` and `and`.

```
(define changingFractions (lambda (X Y)
    (cond 
        ( (and (> X 0) (> Y 0)) (+ (/ X Y) (changingFunctions (- X 1) (- Y 1) )))
        ( (or (= X 0) (= Y 0)) 0)
    )
))
```

Unfortunately, I am still getting an error.

Comment: When something does not "work" correctly, please provide an error message. Here, I guess that `(- x 1)` not being a function is causing a problem. You should try `(changingFunctions (- x 1) (- y 1))` instead of enclosing arguments in parenthesis.

Comment: Do you really need to check that both X and Y are zero if your first test fails? If any of your arguments is negative, the return value of your function is unspecified per cond.

Comment: @coredump- The question is to be completed in an app online. [Here](http://imgur.com/QCRSpYZ) is the error is it giving me. Your first suggestion makes perfect sense and I have adjusted my code, but it is still somehow wrong. I have tried your second suggestion too, which also doesn't solve the problem. I understand that there is no need for it, but I like to have the base case visible.

Comment: Hmm... changingFractions != changingFunctions

Comment: @coredump- My goodness, how did I not spot that in over an hour of trying to solve this! Everything is now working as it should. Thank you!

Comment: You should probably upvote and accept current answer.

Comment: Oh, you already fixed it while I was writing my answer.

Comment: "Unfortunately, I am still getting an error."  It would have helped to have shown that error in the question...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple of problems there:

- You should define a function with the syntax `(define (func-name arg1 arg2 ...) func-body)`, rather than assigning a lambda function to a variable.
- The `and` and `or` are used like functions, by having them as the first element in a form (`(and x y)` rather than `(x and y)`). Not by having them between the arguments.
- You have an extra set of parens around the function parameters for the recursive call, and you wrote `changingFunctions` when the name is `changingFractions`.
- Not an error, but don't put closing parens on their own line.
- The naming convention in Lisps is to use dashes, not camelcase (`changing-fractions` rather than `changingFractions`).

With those fixed:

```
(define (changing-fractions x y)
  (cond 
   ((and (> x 0) (> y 0)) (+ (/ x y) (changing-fractions (- x 1) (- y 1))))
   ((or (= x 0) (= y 0)) 0)))
```

But you could change the `cond` to an `if` to make it clearer:

```
(define (changing-fractions x y)
  (if (and (> x 0) (> y 0))
      (+ (/ x y) (changing-fractions (- x 1) (- y 1)))
      0))
```

Comment: Thank you for all of the corrections. The only issue I don't understand is when/when not to use a lambda function?

Comment: `(define (func p1 p2 ...) ...)` is a shorthand for `(define func (lambda (p1 p2 ...) ...))`.

Comment: @CornOnTheKob Functions made with `lambda` are usually used in an ad hoc manner when you need a function for higher order functions (`map` and such) and the function is either too specific or too trivial to be named, or if the function needs to use variables from the current scope (closure).

Comment: You also use lambdas when you want to delay evaluation.

Answer (score 1):

I personally like this implementation. It has a proper tail call unlike the other answers provided here.

```
(define (changing-fractions x y (z 0))
  (cond ((zero? x) z)
        ((zero? y) z)
        (else (changing-fractions (sub1 x) (sub1 y) (+ z (/ x y))))))

(changing-fractions 4 3) ; => 4 5/6
```

The trick is the optional `z` parameter that defaults to `0`. Using this accumulator, we can iteratively build up the fractional sum each time `changing-fractions` recurses. Compare this to the additional stack frames that are added for each recursion in @jkliski's answer

```
; changing-fractions not in tail position...
(+ (/ x y) (changing-fractions (- x 1) (- y 1)))
```